# Letter for journal's editor about the importance of the paper under review

Tags: publications, journals, editors

I have sent one of the Ph.D. (2019) chapters to a journal two months ago. Today, I found a preprint (Feb 2021) of one of the strongest key authors of my field. Her preprint talking about a similar topic to mine, which I have done two years ago. I send it to multiples journals. Each journal wastes my time for about 3 to 4 months. She is a famous author and may her paper will be published before mine. What should I do now? Do I need to send a letter to the journal editor telling them about this good point about my project. If so, what should I told them.

Comment: I advise you to not send any email.

Comment: It's perfectly fine for two papers to "talk about the same topic". Knowledge would not progress otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that will change nothing. Just be patient.

Comment: Perhaps upload a preprint of your own to establish priority?

Comment: In the ms, if not done yet, refer to your thesis.